# Max & Allexcept combination to find max value by grouping not working, what's wrong?

Tags: filter, powerbi, max, dax, model-driven

I'm quite new to Power BI and DAX but I have what I think should be a pretty simple application of the combination of Max and Allexcept to find the max value of one column, based on the value of another column.

I have one table called EvergradeGroups that contains the group that a product belongs to. Then a Product table which contains the product information for each product, it contains a column called DurabilityPoints which gives a score from 1-10. I want to figure out what the max DurabilityPoints score is for each EvergradeGroup.

Here is the formula I am currently using.

```
DurabilityMax =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( cr481_product[DurabilityPoints] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( cr481_evergradegroups, cr481_evergradegroups[EvergradeGroup] )
)
```

As you can see something is wrong because the first Evergrade group "Blankets & Throws" got a max of 16.5 when the scores only go up to 10. Screenshot of results:
[image: 1]

I have also tried moving the Evergrade groupings into the Product table so that all the information is in the same table. I used a calculated column and the Lookupvalue formula to grab the evergrade groups for each product. However when I then used only product table columns using the formula below, the max scores got even wackier!

```
DurabilityMax =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( cr481_product[DurabilityPoints] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( cr481_product, cr481_product[EvergradeGroup] )
)
```

Here's the results:
[image: 2]

What could I be doing wrong? All the other results seem fine using the first formula, except for that one "Blankets & Throws" group.

Comment: I think you don't need to use AllExcept, all you need to do is `DurabilityMax = MAX(cr481_product[DurabilityPoints])` and make sure that you have a relationship between `EvergradeGroups` and `product` tables

Comment: Please try the suggestion from @Dordi.  If it doesn't bring the expected results, could you provide a small sample of data and expected results?

Comment: Interesting, seems to have helped some. I added a column using your formula and called it DurabilityMaxTest, and the scores are all the same except for the Blankets and Throws, which is still off. As you can see its still scoring above the maximum possible 10 points, and the actual max for that group is 5.5. See Screenshot Here :[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nsWaP6_kLW1t-1SN6Dn8AQBkg5MsVL_9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Here is the sample data and expected results: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FjCvUXRf_Uhza7iCUQ37lHM5dV5w0KFaCHKgjL8mc2A/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I took your sample and tried to reproduce the problem, unfortunately i get the good result, i think you have a problem in your model, here a Screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBEKB.png)

Comment: Thank you, I think I figured it out. There were two subgroups with the same name, these connect to the Evergrade groups causing the issue. Thank you for all your help!